# Xauthority hosed vim's ability to connect to Xserver

Tags: vim, xorg, x-server, xauth

I recently tried to move .Xauthority away from `~/.Xauthority` in a futile attempt to clean up my home directory. Or, rather, I set `$XAUTHORITY` to somewhere else, changed `startx` to `startx -- -auth /somewhere/else`, and thought things would be ok.

They weren't, of course. In the process, my old `.Xauthority` got removed, and now `vim` is broken.

When I try to run vim, I simply get:

```
BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Vim: Got X error
Vim: finished
```

And vim immediately exits. I put everything back how I found it (unset `Xauthority` and removed the `-auth` arg from the call to startx), and still vim dies.

I can, of course, get around this by running `vim -X`, and it looks like there is an error somewhere along the line with `X`, but I can't imagine what. I'm not even sure how to debug this. `xsel` / `xclip` or whatever have no trouble connecting to the X server, so it doesn't look like an Xauthority problem. However, I haven't the slightest idea how to get vim back on it's feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

I was wrong. Xauthority was not the culprit, Xresources was. I had also merged Xdefaults into Xresources (as Xdefaults is deprecated) and had forgotten about it; that merging was the source of my troubles. (I had a naked variable in Xdefaults intended for urxvt which vim was trying to honor, causing it to crash with `invalid parameter attributes`).

My apologies for the confusion.